# MySQL ORDER BY results not alphabetical

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem but have not had any luck. I know there are several similar questions here but they are all more complicated scenarios that do not really apply. Okay, the issue:

I have a very simple table with a list of transaction payees and their associated category. The structure is `id - int`, `name- varchar`, and `cat - varchar`

I am trying to do a simple query to present the payee names in alphabetical order, added to a select box using a `while` loop. Regardless of whether or not I use ASC or DESC, they are displayed in no apparent order There is no white space in the beginning or end of the entries.

Here is the query - `SELECT name FROM payees ORDER BY name`
I have the same result when attempting to sort them alphabetically in phpMyAdmin. `id` is an auto increment int field and the primary key.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is example output - `SELECT name FROM payees ORDER BY name ASC`

- Sheetz
- Walgreens
- Arby's
- Dollar General
- Exxon
- iTunes
- Red Box
- Starbucks
- Walmart

Collation is utf8_unicode_ci

**Solved**

Kudos to @JohnFlatness for solving the puzzle. This turned out to actually be a flaw in code - this project has a mobile and regular version. There was a bug in the scripting of the mobile version that was adding a space to the beginning of the `name` column entries. The entries I spot checked for this were fine, missed the ones that had white space.

Thanks for the help - solved via comments, a first for me lol

Comment: What does a sample of the output data look like? Your query looks fine, so check into what's actually in the data. What's the characterset/collation on the table? That can affect sorting as well e.g. you're on a case-sensitive collation of a-z entries come before A-Z

Comment: it's not the query - it's the display...

Comment: make sure the name field has "Bob" not " Bob" etc.

Comment: @Randy: might be true if OP's code and phpmyadmin differed, but phpmyadmin isn't going to do any sorting other than you specify yourself.

Comment: Where does `name` come from? Unless I'm missing something, your table only has three columns, `id`, `payee` and `cat`

Comment: @Phil - I apologize, had to write fast as the location I was working in was closing. That should be `name`, not `payee`

Comment: @NightMICU So you actually have a column named `name`?

Comment: Looks like aside from Sheetz and Walgreen's, you are getting correct sorting. Maybe you've got some junk at the beginning of those names?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `SELECT HEX(name) FROM payees ORDER BY name ASC`?

Comment: Here's the output for reference: http://sqlize.com/904pho3tUG

Answer (score 1):

Those fields probably do not contain exactly the data you think they do.  Try dumping an output of `SELECT HEX(name) FROM payees` to show exactly what is in each field.  Here is what the output *should* be for reference:

```
417262792773                    Arby's
446F6C6C61722047656E6572616C    Dollar General
4578786F6E                      Exxon
6954756E6573                    iTunes
52656420426F78                  Red Box
53686565747A                    Sheetz
537461726275636B73              Starbucks
57616C677265656E73              Walgreens
57616C6D617274                  Walmart
```

Demo: http://sqlize.com/904pho3tUG

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM payees ORDER BY trim(name)
```

Also verify your table collation ends in *_ci